# Отслеживать события в NET ListView с помощью библиотеки

Tags: c#, c++

Возможно ли отслеживать события в `ListView` на `NET` форме.
Вся сложность в том что хочу отслеживать события через библиотеку, написанную на С++.
То есть сам код вызова предполагается банально через `DllImport`

```
[DllImport("..\\..\\PinvokeLib.dll")]  
public static extern void WndProc(IntPtr listViewHandle);
```

Идеально было бы запилить в С++ некий аналог "`WndProc(ref Message m)`".

P.S.
Такая заморочка нужна для защиты, в этой же сишной библиотеке будут другие функции, важные для работы утилиты.

Спасибо.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но скорее всего либо придётся под каждое событие ListView городить забор из библиотечных вызовов, либо найти какой-то универсальный способ передачи описателя события в библиотечную функцию. Например, ловить событие в коде C#, запихивать его описание в строчку и передавать в библиотеку С++. Это пример применения грубой силы, наверняка есть какие-то более элегантные способы :)

Comment: WinForms или WPF? В WPF контролы не являются окнами.

Comment: Да - код на C# доступен  
>>> пусть сама программа узнаёт об изменениях  
В том то и дело, что NET код легко декомпилируется, то есть этот запрос можно "выпилить".

Comment: Если хотите переложить обработку сообщений на библиотеку, при этом не делать прямую передачу, нужно смотреть в сторону хуков для WndProc. Структура примерно такая:
** В нативной библиотеке реализуете установку хука по хэндлу контрола, создаете функцию как в Вашем вопросе.
** В C#, после создания ListView просто  вызываете эту функцию передавая хэндл, а нативная библиотека повесит хук и будет обрабатывать сообщения.

Comment: А есть ли конкретно хуки на выбор item?  
Хотя конечно можно просто отрабатывать хуки на клики мыши и нажатие клавиш...  
И еще - возможно ли создать одну библиотеку для x32 и x64 windows?